# Django and reading data from .xls file?

Tags: python, django, excel

I've got a .xls file (maybe 800+ rows of data) with columns like this:

Name | Value1 | Value2 | Value3... up to Value 20

I want to use it in a form in Django. If someone puts in the "name" - it checks if it's in the file and populates the other fields with data. (Maybe even show a list with suggestions if you write the first letter..)

Whats the best way of doing this?

- Just use the file as it is (?) and import some library to read .xls.
- Store the data in a list/dictionary varible in forms.py?
- Store the data in a variable in my .js file?
- Create a new model/table in my database and read in all the data once?

Comment: Why isn't the data in a database, instead of an Excel file?

Comment: Well I don't know.. That's what I'm wondering. Should write a script to handle the data and put it in a table in the db? (Maybe a stupid question..)

Comment: Yeah, write a [fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/).

Comment: Are you using `.xls` files or `.xlsx`?

Comment: Check http://www.python-excel.org for recommendations on Python packages to use with Excel files.

Comment: mfcovington, thanks! I think ill use xlrd library but i wasn't sure when to put it in the db or just a key-val dict? Don't know the limits here. But maybe it's always better in the db.

Comment: put it in the database.